# MySql using bit-field literals aka binary numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, binary

```
SET @var = b'01011010';
SELECT BIN(@var);
```

Note that 01011010 == 'Z';

Returns:

```
+-----------+
| BIN(@var) |
+-----------+
| 0         |
+-----------+
```

MySql [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html) states:

"Bit values are returned as binary values. To display them in printable form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN(). "

Why does this conversion function not work properly and to actually get 'Z' all you need to do is select @var:

```
SELECT @var;
+------+
| @var |
+------+
| Z    |
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
mysql> SELECT BIN(ORD(@var));
+----------------+
| BIN(ORD(@var)) |
+----------------+
| 1011010        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`BIN()` accepts numeric type. so you need to convert `z` to `90`.

```
mysql>  SELECT @var, ORD(@var), BIN('Z'), BIN(90);
+------+-----------+----------+---------+
| @var | ORD(@var) | BIN('Z') | BIN(90) |
+------+-----------+----------+---------+
| Z    |        90 | 0        | 1011010 |
+------+-----------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It could turn out alright but I am trying to understand how they got the values from this section: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html